# Most elegant image to image frame comparison algorithm

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in finding the most elegant and 'correct' solution to this problem. I'm new to JS/PHP and I'm really excited to be working with it. The goal is to compare the size of a given image to the size of a 'frame' for the image (going to be a `<div>` or `<li>` eventually) and resize the image accordingly. Users will be uploading images of many sizes and shapes and there are going to be many sizes and shapes of frames. The goal is to make sure that any given image will be correctly resized to fit any given frame. Additionally, images will be cropped with `overflow:hidden;` so they'll never be distorted. Final implementation will be in PHP, but I'm working out the logic in JS. Here's what I have:

```
//predefined variables generated dynamically from other parts of script, these are example values showing the 'landscape in landscape' ratio issue
var $imageHeight = 150, $imageWidth = 310, $height = 240, $width = 300;         
//check image orientation
if ( $imageHeight == $imageWidth ) {
    var $imageType = 1; // square image
} else if ( $imageHeight > $imageWidth ) {
    var $imageType = 2; // portrait image
} else {
    var $imageType = 3; // landscape image
};
//check frame orientation and compare to image orientation
if ( $height == $width) { //square frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 3 ) ) {
        $deferToHeight = true;
    } else {
        $deferToHeight = false;
    };
} else if  ( $height > $width ) { //portrait frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 3 ) )  {
        $deferToHeight = true;
    } else {
        if (($imageHeight / $height) < 1) {
                $deferToHeight = true;
            } else {
                $deferToHeight = false;
        };
    };
} else { //landscape frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 2 ) ) {
        $deferToHeight = false;
    } else {
        if (($imageWidth / $width) > 1) {
                $deferToHeight = true;
            } else {
                $deferToHeight = false;
        };
    };
};
//set values to match (null value scales proportionately)
if ($deferToHeight == true) { //defer image size to height of frame
    $imageWidth = null;
    $imageHeight = $height;
} else { //defer image size to width of frame
    $imageWidth = $width;
    $imageHeight = null;
};
```

I've tested it with a bunch of different values and it *works*, but I have a suspicion that I could have implemented a much more elegant solution. What could I have done better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we move past rewriting the boolean expressions and instead rework the formulas, I think we can get something a little easier to manage.

If I understand correctly, your goal is to have the image *cover* the frame. That is to say, for the frame to be filled and the image cropped.

In that case, All we need to do is scale the image to the frame.

```
var imageHeight = 150, imageWidth = 310, height = 240, width = 300;

//Find the larget discrepancy between frame size and corresponding image size
var scaleRatio = Math.max( height/imageHeight, width/imageWidth );

//Apply the scale to the whole image.
imageHeight *= scaleRatio;
imageWidth *= scaleRatio;
```

If instead your desire it to have the image *fit* in the frame, then all we need to do is replace `Math.max` with `Math.min`.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I will be referring to each top level commit as a section.*

First off, in section 3:

```
if ($imageHeight / $height) < 1) {
   $deferToHeight = true;
} else {
   $deferToHeight = false;
}
```

can become

```
$deferToHeight = ($imageHeight < $height);
```

Next, we can reorder section 3 into:

```
if ( $imageType === 1 ){
   if ( $height == $width ) { //square frame
      $deferToHeight = true;
   } else if  ( $height > $width ) { //portrait frame
      $deferToHeight = true;
   } else { //landscape frame
      $deferToHeight = false;
   }
} else if //... etc
```

which will allow us to then condense it further into:

```
if($imageType === 1){
   $deferToHeight = ($height >= $width);
} else if ($imageType === 2){
   $deferToHeight = ($height > $width && $imageHeight < $height)  
} else if ($imageType === 3){
   $deferToHeight = ($height >= $width || $imageWidth > $width)
}
```

Now let us merge section 2 and 3 and Voilà!

```
var $imageHeight = 150, $imageWidth = 310, $height = 240, $width = 300;

if ( $imageHeight == $imageWidth ) {
   var $deferToHeight = (height >= width);
} else if ( $imageHeight > $imageWidth ) {
   var $deferToHeight = ($height > $width && $imageHeight < $height)  
} else {
   var $deferToHeight = ($height >= $width || $imageWidth > $width)
}

//And lets even make the last section a little shorter:
$imageWidth = ($deferToHeight ? null : $width);
$imageHeight = ($deferToHeight ? $height : null);
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks really good. I'll need to play with to really understand it. Quick question, by setting a variable to `($height > $width)` you're effectively building a boolean test?

Comment: How would you account for cases in which the ratio of the image width to the frame width is greater than that of the image height to the frame height? For example, in the supplied values we end up with an image that fills the frame horizontally, but not vertically. In those cases, we must defer to the height. If I'm reading your version correctly, we'll end up deferring to the width.

Comment: Yes. `if(x > y){ a = true } else { a = false }` is the same as `a = (x > y)`. 

As for the width issue, I do believe you are correct. Either way, my version generates the same result as your version, so something is wrong with the general formula. See my [second answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9048/10797) for a different approach to this problem.